# Run Appium Inspector for application running in a real iDevice

Tags: ios, iphone, appium

We can run Appium inspector for applications running on an iPhone Simulator and get the locators like Xpath etc.

Is there any way to run Appium Inspector for application running in a real iPhone or any other iDevice and  get the locators?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Appium Inspector in the same way while running on real device as you have been using it while running on simulator. 
Just launch app and run code and click on 'i' icon to view Appium Inspector.

Comment: Are you sure , this is possible?

Comment: I have been using it myself this way.

Comment: @samriti : Its not working as u said ....As soon as i open Appium Inspector while running on Real device ,the app on Real device closes and i can not record further ....

Comment: @Samyukt : do you have 'prelaunch application' option as set in Appium preferences? Also let me know what all are your capabilties set in code?

Comment: @Smriti: Yes 'Prelaunch application' option is set in Appium preferences.                                                        Launching Application on Real Device works great ,but as soon as i click on 'i' icon to open Appium Inspector to be able to record ,the App on Real device closes .

Comment: What all capabilites you are setting in the code? And any errors in logs you are seeing in Appium?

Comment: Capabilities setting in code ? (i am not launching app using any code , i am using Appium App for MAC http://appium.io/ )                   DO you mean capabilities setting in appium preferences iOS Settings ?                                                                    I am setting below mentioned capabilities: App Path ,BundleID,UDID,Force Device:iPhone,Patform Version: 7.1 .